# Extracting a specific key from JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm working with the requests library, Python 3.6, and an SMS platform's Swagger API. 
I'm a little bit confused as to how I would extract a specific key:value from this JSON hierarchy.

Here is the URL to the API documentation:
[api docs](https://api.kenect.com/swagger-ui.html#/Conversations-v1)

I am trying to query the endpoint for a specific phone number based on an ID.

This is the URL to query: https://api.kenect.com/v1/conversations/****ID***

Here is the JSON hierarchy, so I would like to use the 'phoneNumbers' key and the 'number' value:

```
    {
  "archiveDate": 1514801105185,
  "assignedTeamId": 0,
  "assignedTeamName": "string",
  "assignedUser": {
    "departmentId": 1234,
    "firstName": "John",
    "id": 1234,
    "inactiveDate": 1514801105185,
    "includeSignature": true,
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "messageSignature": "Best, John Doe",
    "username": "jdoe@mymail.com"
  },
  "contact": {
    "createdDate": 1514801105185,
    "emailAddress": "contact@email.com",
    "externalId": "8adf-7865",
    "firstActiveDate": 1514801105185,
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "groups": [
      {
        "createdDate": 1514801105185,
        "id": 1234,
        "locationId": 1234,
        "name": "the inner circle",
        "updatedDate": 1514801105185
      }
    ],
    "id": 1234,
    "inactiveDate": 1514801105185,
    "lastContacted": 1514801105185,
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "locationId": 12345,
    "note": "string",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "city": "Pleasant Grove",
        "country": "US",
        "createdDate": 1514801105185,
        "id": 1234,
        "messageOptInDate": 1514801105185,
        "messageStopDate": 1514801105185,
        "number": "+18015552671",
        "primary": true,
        "sentOptInMessageDate": 1514801105185,
        "smsCapable": true,
        "state": "UT",
        "status": true,
        "type": "CELL",
        "updatedDate": 1514801105185,
        "zipCode": 84062
      }
    ],
    "reviewRequestSent": 1514801105185,
    "source": "LIGHTSPEED",
    "updatedDate": 1514801105185
  },
  "createdDate": 1514801105185,
  "dataAssigned": 0,
  "id": 1234,
  "lastMessageType": "FACEBOOK",
  "lastSent": 1514801105185,
  "locationId": 0,
  "messages": [
    {
      "assignedUserId": 0,
      "attachments": [
        {
          "contentType": "string",
          "createdDate": 1514801105185,
          "friendlyName": "string",
          "id": 1234,
          "md5": "string",
          "size": 16384,
          "thumbnailBase64": "string",
          "updatedDate": 1514801105185
        }
      ],
      "body": "string",
      "contactId": 0,
      "conversationId": 0,
      "error": "string",
      "id": 1234,
      "kind": "string",
      "locationId": 0,
      "outgoing": true,
      "readDate": 0,
      "respondedDate": 0,
      "reviewRequest": true,
      "sentDate": 0,
      "status": "string",
      "type": "FACEBOOK"
    }
  ],
  "newConversation": true,
  "read": true,
  "responded": true,
  "snippet": "string",
  "subject": "string",
  "updatedDate": 1514801105185
}
```

And finally, here is the code I am trying. I had used a similar function to obtain the message body from this same endpoint, but it's not working for the phone number.

```
url='https://api.kenect.com/v1/conversations/'
h = {'accept': recContentType,
    'content-type': recContentType,
    'x-api-token': apiToken,
    'x-api-Key': apiKey}
p={'id': id}

response=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p).json()

for item in response['phoneNumber']:
    pnum = item['number']
    print(pnum)
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: It's phoneNumber**s**, and it's inside contact

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: the error I was getting was 'KeyError: 'phoneNumbers' ... because I didn't understand how to specify that it's inside contact. Thank you for pointing that out for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the path you'll need to access to get to number:

```
.contact.phoneNumbers[0].number
```

So, you'll need this:

```
number = response['contact']['phoneNumbers'][0]['number']
print(number)
```

Or editing your code:

```
url='https://api.kenect.com/v1/conversations/'
h = {'accept': recContentType,
    'content-type': recContentType,
    'x-api-token': apiToken,
    'x-api-Key': apiKey}
p={'id': id}

response=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p).json()

for item in response['contact']['phoneNumbers']:
    pnum = item['number']
    print(pnum)
```

As per the comments below, the code above can result in errors if a field in the json is missing.  For instance, if a `reponse` doesn't have  a `contact` there will be an issue.

Consider adding some more bullet proofing to the code above as follows:

```
url='https://api.kenect.com/v1/conversations/'
h = {'accept': recContentType,
    'content-type': recContentType,
    'x-api-token': apiToken,
    'x-api-Key': apiKey}
p={'id': id}

response=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p).json()

if response:
  if 'contact' in response:
    if 'phoneNumbers' in response['contact']:
      for item in response['contact']['phoneNumbers']:
        pnum = item['number']
        print(pnum)
```

I *think* there is enough checking in the new version of code to avoid the error you described in the comments below.  Now, we only process the response when it is non empty and when it contains a `contact` key which in turn   has to contain the `phoneNumbers` key.  There is still an opportunity to print None, when a phoneNumber doesn't contain a number, but that won't generate an error.  Just be aware that pnum could be None.

Comment: Thank you so much for spelling it all out for me simply. However, when I do like you suggested I get 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: Hi boog, that error occurs when the json structure doesn't contain the field that you are looking for.   I'll submit a modification that checks for a field before accessing it.

Comment: I would appreciate that. That is odd, because if you look at the API's documentation for that endpoint... the json model shows that phone number is included... however when I GET everything from the endpoint, no phone numbers returned. Maybe the documentation is off? It does say the api is v0.0.0.1 - beta, after all

Comment: Let me know how it goes for you - I added the additional code 4 hours ago - go to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Oh, oops- just noticed you already updated your post. I tried it out and while your code works well and does what it's supposed to do, it still just doesn't return anything because there is no phoneNumbers in the response at all... the api documentation is incorrect, or so it seems